# Why visual studio 2022 can't debug nothing?

Tags: blazor, progressive-web-apps, visual-studio-2022

I create empty blazor wasm in VS22, run with F5 and getting this:
[image: debugger error]

Error translates as: Failed to start debug adapter. Additional information may be available in the output window.

Visual studio, always show this error, on each projects, default empty or other's people projects. Seems some debug tools are not installed or what? How to fix this problem, whats is may be?

I tryed delete and install VS22, install .NET SDK 6 and 7, last .NET CORE 3

Update:

I even no have readable error message log. The output in VS22 is:

```
"BlazorApp.Server.exe" (CoreCLR: clrhost). Loaded "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.0\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll". Symbol loading skipped. The module is optimized, the debugger option "Just my code" is enabled.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: https://localhost:7215
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: http://localhost:5183
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Development
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path: D:\Projects\BlazorUI_Demos\AntDesign4\BlazorApp\Server
Failed to start debug adapter "pwa-chrome".
Failed to launch debug server process due to:



Program "" exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).
Program "[15368] BlazorApp.Server.exe" exited with code 3221225786 (0xc000013a).
Program "[15368] BlazorApp.Server.exe: Program trace" exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with Visual Studio 2022 or Blazor.  I've been using it since the first Preview for a reporting site built using Blazor Wasm. You haven't provided any information. Not even a readable error message

Comment: On Windows you can copy the contents of a message box with Ctrl+C. This will copy the title, text and buttons as text instead of an image. This way you can google the text message.  At the very least translate the message so we can understand what this says.

Comment: This is the question, what is going on here. I have only this message about "some error happened" thx microsoft! And log says the same. I show you in update of question above

Comment: The debug console is in Russian, this is an international discussion forum. Please use English if you intend on finding support.

Comment: Updated with english

Comment: Which browser are you using? Debugging Blazor WASM only works in Chromium based browsers

Answer (score -1):

I found some answers here and is worked for me to launch app without debugger. After enable hot restarting in debug settings [The Visual Studio 2022 Error "Failed to launch debug adapter. Additional information may be available in the output window."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70374907/the-visual-studio-2022-error-failed-to-launch-debug-adapter-additional-informa)
but the question now, is how to make debugger work?