# VS2022 start debugging gives Failed to launch debug adapter. unable to attach to browser

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to start debugging a Blazor WASM solution and I get this error:

[image]

this is the console output windows:

```
got exception System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to the remote server
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:1080)
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|277_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectToTcpHostAsync(String host, Int32 port, HttpRequestMessage initialRequest, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.EstablishProxyTunnelAsync(Boolean async, HttpRequestHeaders headers, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation`1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ClientWebSocketOptions options)
at System.Net.WebSockets.WebSocketHandle.ConnectAsync(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken, ClientWebSocketOptions options)
at System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket.ConnectAsyncCore(Uri uri, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.DevToolsProxy.Run(Uri browserUri, WebSocket ideSocket)
at Microsoft.WebAssembly.Diagnostics.DebugExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<<UseDebugProxy>g__ConnectProxy|5>d.MoveNext()
```

Any help? what's causing the problem?

this is launchSettings.json

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:13139",
      "sslPort": 44318
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "Bulut.Appraisal.Frontend": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:6080;http://localhost:6081",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I feel like this was thoroughly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70374907/the-visual-studio-2022-error-failed-to-launch-debug-adapter-additional-informa):